# VBA Userform Images are Different Sizes or Lose Fidelity between Computers

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am using images as buttons on VBA userforms. This works fine on one computer, but when I view the same userforms on another computer the images do not display correctly.

If I set PictureSizeMode for the image to fmPictureSizeModeClip then it is too large for the image area on the second computer - and the picture is clipped. If I set PictureSizeMode to fmPictureSizeModeZoom, it scales correctly for the image area on the second computer, but it loses a lot of fidelity (it looks terrible). In both cases the images are fine on the first computer.

The original image format of the images was jpg.

I've tried changing screen resolutions on both the computer where I developed the code and the second computer that has the problem. I am not able to reproduce the problem on the first computer in this way (I also have an ancient monitor attached to it, and that also displays fine). I am not able to make the problem going away on the second computer either by doing this.

These are screenshots of the images as shown selected in the VBE:

On the first computer where it all displays correctly (whether set to clip mode or zoom mode it looks the same):
http://code.commtap.org/vba/userform-images/no-problems-computer1.png

On the second computer - PictureSizeMode set to fmPictureSizeModeClip:
http://code.commtap.org/vba/userform-images/clipped-computer2.png
And PictureSizeMode set to fmPictureSizeModeZoom:
http://code.commtap.org/vba/userform-images/scaled-loss-of-fidelity-computer2.png

- [pptm file with the form](http://code.commtap.org/vba/userform-images/image-on-form-problem.pptm)
- [screenshot - form displaying correctly](http://code.commtap.org/vba/userform-images/form-displaying-correctly.png)
- [screenshot - form displaying poorly](http://code.commtap.org/vba/userform-images/form-displaying-poorly.png)
- [an original image used in the form](http://code.commtap.org/vba/userform-images/symbolise-enabled.jpg)

Comment: What is your version of PowerPoint?

Comment: And are you possibly moving this between Windows and Mac computers?

Comment: It's all Windows (no Macs involved). PowerPoint version: Office 365 Version 1906 (Build 11727.20210 Click-to-Run) on both computers.

Comment: Also, running PowerPoint in a virtual machine on the first computer (Windows 10 in VirtualBox, same Office version) has the same userform image problem.

Comment: What about the dpi settings on the two computers?  Same or different?

Comment: Different. On the first computer (displaying nicely) it works out as 142dpi, and on the second one 100dpi (or thereabouts).

Comment: More info on displays: Computer1 - laptop display: 142dpi, attached display: 96dpi - displays fine on both. VM (on computer1) - laptop display: 138dpi, attached display: 93dpi - image cropped on both.

Comment: Added links to a pptm file generating this form and screenshots of the form.

Answer (score 0):

I've found no way to satisfactorily size pictures so that they always look right on different machines, so the solution I have come up with is to size the rest of the form around the pictures.

To do this:

- Set PictureSizeMode for the images to fmPictureSizeModeClip.
- Get the measurement (in points) of the height or width of one image in the form on a machine where it looks right.
- Set the dimensions of the form and the controls based on the change in dimensions of this image.

```
    Private Sub AdjustFormSize()

      Dim dblDefaultRefImageHeight As Double
      ' This is the height of the reference image as computed on the
      ' machine where it looks right:
      dblDefaultRefImageHeight = 1947

      Dim dblActualRefImageHeight As Double
      dblActualRefImageHeight = Me.ImgRefImage.Picture.Height

      Dim dblSizeFactor As Double
      dblSizeFactor = dblActualRefImageHeight / dblDefaultRefImageHeight

      Me.Height = Me.Height * dblSizeFactor
      Me.Width = Me.Width * dblSizeFactor

      Dim ctlControl As Control

      For Each ctlControl In Me.Controls
        ctlControl.Top = ctlControl.Top * dblSizeFactor
        ctlControl.Left = ctlControl.Left * dblSizeFactor

        ctlControl.Height = ctlControl.Height * dblSizeFactor
        ctlControl.Width = ctlControl.Width * dblSizeFactor

        If TypeName(ctlControl) = "Label" Then
          ctlControl.Font.Size = ctlControl.Font.Size * dblSizeFactor
        End If
      Next ctlControl

    End Sub
```

Put this in the userform, and call it when the form is created - for example from UserForm_Initialize().