# Images in VBA UserForm change between computers

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I created my first userform and I am using images as buttons to obtain a "hover" effect on the okay and cancel button. I currently have my laptop plugged in an external monitor and when I move the form from the monitor to the laptop everything is fine. However, when I start the macro without the external monitor plugged in, the pictures are much smaller.

I found two solutions looking on this forum: one is to optimize for compatibility, but it doesn't solve my problem and the graphic quality on my laptop becomes terrible. The second is the code in this answer: [VBA Userform Images are Different Sizes or Lose Fidelity between Computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56788770/vba-userform-images-are-different-sizes-or-lose-fidelity-between-computers), which also didn't solve my problem.

I will need this form to circulate around and be used on different computers, that is why I am worried about this scaling problem. Hope someone can help, thank you in advance!

[Buttons OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTsTl.jpg)

[Buttons get messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ubmK.jpg)

Comment: Is it only the images that scale?  What about the other controls?

Comment: @SeniorMomentum only the images, everything else looks fine. I will try to edit the post and add a couple of images of what I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are the properties of an image that I use as a basis for buttons.  I don't appear to be having scaling issues so maybe you could try these properties.
[image]

Comment: Okay so the only difference was in PictureSizeMode, I had clip. I changed it to Stretch and now it seems to be solved. However, it's like the images lost quality, I see the words more "pixelated" if it makes sense. Do you have any idea on how to correct that?

Comment: Could you try saving the original image at a higher resolution?

Comment: Not sure how, originally I created the buttons on Excel (single cell, format backgound ecc.), now I tried to use powerpoint with shapes and the result is even worst.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I had to create the shapes on Excel and the result is much better. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

it is because your two screens have too high a resolution
so use the event layout of the userform and in this event reset your images in your buttons

Comment: You mean in the UserForm_Initialize section? And how would I reset the images?